# Modulo operator, how to do Binary % bigint?

Tags: sql-server, binary-data, modulo, bigint

MSDN [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) that valid types for Modulo are

> data types in the integer and monetary data type categories, or the numeric data type

BINARY is not in a list, but still I can do

```
DECLARE 
  @a bigint = 1, 
  @b bigint = 2, 
  @bin binary(16)

SET @bin = cast(@a AS binary(8)) + cast(@b AS binary(8))

PRINT @bin % 2147483647
```

BIGINT is in the list, but this doesn't work:

```
PRINT @bin % 9223372036854775807
```

My question, is it possible to do BINARY % BIGINT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, SQL server implicitly treats `9223372036854775807` as `numeric` (decimal) and so is not supported by the `%` operator.

You just need to cast it to a `bigint` first:

```
DECLARE 
  @a bigint = 1, 
  @b bigint = 2, 
  @bin binary(16)

SET @bin = cast(@a AS binary(8)) + cast(@b AS binary(8))

PRINT @bin % 2147483647
PRINT @bin % CONVERT(bigint, 9223372036854775807)
```

[I think] this happens because `numeric` (`decimal`) has higher type precedence than `bigint`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. It is counter-intuitive, why it converts max bigint to numeric though.